# error_reporting(0) not affecting error display on page:

Tags: php, error-reporting

error_reporting(0) not affecting error display on page:

I am checking my website on localhost server (XAMPP) and I want to hide any errors from visitors of my website.

However, I have tried to add custom message for visitors so they won't able to get actual error and instead I logged that error to error.log file on server, but what if I don't want to do either of any two ?

To set error_reporting(0) / ini_set('display_errors',0); on script won't working for me and its anyhow reporting error to error log

> CODE :

```
ini_set('display_errors',0);
error_reporting(0);
$query = "SELECT * FROM user1 WHERE uname = '34'";   //User1 not exist, I     wrote this to get error

mysql_query($query) 
or 
die(errorhandler($query,mysql_error()));

function errorhandler($query,$error){

  $pesan = htmlspecialchars("Failed Query: ". 
  $query ."<br>".$error );

  error_log($pesan,3,"error.log");   // This will log error to error.log file 

  return "page not exists, try other.";   // User will see this message, no     matter what error is 
}
```

Please don't suggest to return "" instead "page not exists, try other.";

Comment: For me its getting as expected. The only change for me may be the php ini file configuration and htaccess file but the error_reporting() will overwrite the above two.

Comment: It is giving me error :
Table 'db_session.user1'  (If ignore error_log function) doesn't exist which should not be there if error_reporting(0) right ?

Comment: Can you add this line as well to specify the error log file path
ini_set('error_log', '/path/to/php-error.log');

Comment: Still same error :
Table 'db_session.user1' doesn't exist
When i try to echo variable,it is giving error that $abc not defined, but when I add ini_set("display_errors", "0") in script,it disappered, so wondering why this table not found error still coming up as it should also disappered

Comment: As per this tutotial : http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
It should turn off all error with error_reporting(0); , but for me ,error of "Table 'db_session.user1' doesn't exist" coming up anyhow

Comment: Can you try commenting all other code than the return statement from errorhandler() and check what is the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76012/discussion-between-lerry-and-sanjay-kumar-n-s).